Error "Caused by: org.gradle.api.UnknownDomainObjectException: SourceSet with name 'commonTest' not found." while trying to register a gradle task
I have the following issue with Android Studio in my Kotlin Multiplatform Project.
I want to add conformance tests to my project and for this i wanted to add a new source set and have all the test files in there. But everytime i want to register a task to being able to trigger the conformance tests by my pipeline separately from the other tests, i get the following error Message:
> Task :prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE
Failed building KotlinMPPGradleModel
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreationException: Could not create task ':shared:conformanceTest'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.taskCreationException(DefaultTaskContainer.java:721)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.access$600(DefaultTaskContainer.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreatingProvider.domainObjectCreationException(DefaultTaskContainer.java:713)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection$AbstractDomainObjectCreatingProvider.tryCreate(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:948)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreatingProvider.access$1401(DefaultTaskContainer.java:660)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreatingProvider$1.run(DefaultTaskContainer.java:686)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreatingProvider.tryCreate(DefaultTaskContainer.java:682)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection$AbstractDomainObjectCreatingProvider.calculateOwnValue(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:929)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.Collectors$ElementFromProvider.collectEntries(Collectors.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.Collectors$TypedCollector.collectEntries(Collectors.java:334)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.Collectors$TypedCollector.collectInto(Collectors.java:329)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.collections.DefaultPendingSource.realize(DefaultPendingSource.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.collections.DefaultPendingSource.realizePending(DefaultPendingSource.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.collections.SortedSetElementSource.iterator(SortedSetElementSource.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.iterator(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:128)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.iterator(DefaultTaskContainer.java:626)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.gradleTooling.builders.KotlinTargetBuilder.buildTestRunTasks(KotlinTargetBuilder.kt:230)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.gradleTooling.builders.KotlinTargetBuilder.buildComponent(KotlinTargetBuilder.kt:50)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.gradleTooling.KotlinMPPGradleModelBuilder.buildTargets(KotlinMPPGradleModelBuilder.kt:123)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.gradleTooling.KotlinMPPGradleModelBuilder.buildAll(KotlinMPPGradleModelBuilder.kt:58)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.gradleTooling.KotlinMPPGradleModelBuilder.buildAll(KotlinMPPGradleModelBuilder.kt:37)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.gradleTooling.KotlinMPPGradleModelBuilder.buildAll(KotlinMPPGradleModelBuilder.kt:25)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder.buildAll(ExtraModelBuilder.java:107)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder.buildAll(ExtraModelBuilder.java:76)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$BuilderWithParameter.build(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:287)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$UserCodeAssigningBuilder.lambda$build$0(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:374)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication.reapply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$UserCodeAssigningBuilder.build(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:374)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$LockSingleProjectBuilder.lambda$build$0(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:304)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$fromMutableState$2(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:418)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withReplacedLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:345)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:418)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$LockSingleProjectBuilder.build(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:304)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$BuildOperationWrappingBuilder$1.call(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:337)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$BuildOperationWrappingBuilder.build(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:334)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildToolingModelController$AbstractToolingScope.getModel(DefaultBuildToolingModelController.java:82)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getModel(DefaultBuildController.java:106)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.getModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:113)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.findModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:97)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.findModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.findModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:81)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.findModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction$MyBuildController.findModel(ProjectImportAction.java:658)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ClassSetProjectImportModelProvider.populateProjectModels(ClassSetProjectImportModelProvider.java:31)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.getProjectModels(ProjectImportAction.java:338)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.access$500(ProjectImportAction.java:42)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction$4.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:249)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction$4.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:246)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.fetchProjectBuildModels(ProjectImportAction.java:262)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.runAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:131)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.fromBuildModel(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:104)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.fromBuildModel(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:84)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.fromBuildModel(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$fromBuildModel$2(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:81)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$6(StateTransitionController.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$7(StateTransitionController.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:95)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.fromBuildModel(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:73)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:65)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:140)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.execute(InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.continuous.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:50)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UnknownDomainObjectException: SourceSet with name 'commonTest' not found.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.createNotFoundException(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:504)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.getByName(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:333)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.NamedDomainObjectCollectionExtensionsKt.get(NamedDomainObjectCollectionExtensions.kt:401)
    at Build_gradle$2.invoke(build.gradle.kts:90)
    at Build_gradle$2.invoke(build.gradle.kts:87)
    at Build_gradle$inlined$sam$i$org_gradle_api_Action$0.execute(TaskContainerExtensions.kt)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultMutationGuard$1.execute(DefaultMutationGuard.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultMutationGuard$1.execute(DefaultMutationGuard.java:45)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:110)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:107)
    at org.gradle.internal.ImmutableActionSet$SetWithManyActions.execute(ImmutableActionSet.java:329)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:262)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:256)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection$AbstractDomainObjectCreatingProvider.tryCreate(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:944)
    ... 153 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UnknownDomainObjectException: SourceSet with name 'commonTest' not found.


Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.2.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.


This is my gradle file where i define the sourceSets:
sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                //put your multiplatform dependencies here
                api(libs.kotlinx.datetime)
                implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.core)
                api(libs.bundles.ktor)
                api(libs.kotlin.reflection)
                api(libs.kotlin.stdlib)
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))

                // reference: https://kotest.io/docs/quickstart/#assertions-library
                implementation(libs.kotest.kotest.assertions.core)

                // reference: https://kotest.io/docs/framework/project-setup.html
                implementation(libs.kotest.framework.engine)

                // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.mockk/mockk-common
                implementation(libs.mockk.common)

                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            dependencies {
                implementation(libs.appauth)
                implementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
                implementation(libs.androidx.junit)
                implementation(libs.mockk.android)
                implementation(libs.ktor.client.android)
            }
        }

        val androidUnitTest by getting {
            dependsOn(androidMain)
            dependsOn(commonTest)
        }

        val androidInstrumentedTest by getting {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            dependsOn(androidMain)
        }

        val conformanceTest by creating {
            kotlin.srcDir("src/shared/conformanceTests/kotlin")
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            dependsOn(androidMain)
        }
    }

Here is the gradle file:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.multiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.android.library)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.serialization)
}

@OptIn(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
kotlin {
    targetHierarchy.default()

    android {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = libs.versions.jvmTarget.get()
            }
        }
    }

    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "shared"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                //put your multiplatform dependencies here
                api(libs.kotlinx.datetime)
                implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.core)
                api(libs.bundles.ktor)
                api(libs.kotlin.reflection)
                api(libs.kotlin.stdlib)
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))

                // reference: https://kotest.io/docs/quickstart/#assertions-library
                implementation(libs.kotest.kotest.assertions.core)

                // reference: https://kotest.io/docs/framework/project-setup.html
                implementation(libs.kotest.framework.engine)

                // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.mockk/mockk-common
                implementation(libs.mockk.common)

                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            dependencies {
                implementation(libs.appauth)
                implementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
                implementation(libs.androidx.junit)
                implementation(libs.mockk.android)
                implementation(libs.ktor.client.android)
            }
        }

        val androidUnitTest by getting {
            dependsOn(androidMain)
            dependsOn(commonTest)
        }

        val androidInstrumentedTest by getting {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            dependsOn(androidMain)
        }

        val conformanceTest by creating {
            kotlin.srcDir("src/shared/conformanceTests/kotlin")
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            dependsOn(androidMain)
        }
    }
}

tasks.register<Test>("conformanceTest") {
    group = "verification"
    description = "Runs the conformance tests."
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets["conformanceTest"].output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets["conformanceTest"].runtimeClasspath
    include("**/*Test.class")
    filter {
        includeTestsMatching("*Conformance*")
    }
}

android {
    lint {
        // If set to true (default), stops the build if errors are found.
        abortOnError = false
        // If set to true, lint only reports errors.
        ignoreWarnings = false
        // If set to true, lint also checks all dependencies as part of its analysis.
        // Recommended for projects consisting of an app with library dependencies.
        checkDependencies = true
    }

    namespace = "com.docuware.cygnus"
    compileSdk = libs.versions.targetSdk.get().toInt()
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = libs.versions.minSdk.get().toInt()
        manifestPlaceholders["appAuthRedirectScheme"] = "cygnus"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    // Throws 2 files found with path 'win32-x86-64/attach_hotspot_windows.dll' otherwise
    packaging {
        resources.excludes.add("**/attach_hotspot_windows.dll")
        resources.excludes.add("META-INF/**")
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion(libs.versions.jvmTarget.get())
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion(libs.versions.jvmTarget.get())
    }
}

When i try to adress the sourceSet in the registration like kotlin.sourceSets["conformanceTest"] i get the following errors from the precompiler: Unresolved reference: output and Unresolved reference: runtimeClasspath
Any ideas what I'm missing? I already asked 2 colleagues and ChatGPT 4.o, but none could save this problem so far even though my colleague could reproduce it on his machine by checking out my branch and trying to sync.
Looking forward to your answers and thanks already in advance.
Maverick
Update
I managed to make it sync with enclosing the setting of the classpath and testClassesDirs inside a doFirst{} block.
Unfortunately the testClassesDirs is null when i try to execute the task, so any additional help would be appreciated.

As i found out, i just need to set the classpath to my task like this:
val testCompilation = kotlin.targets["jvm"].compilations["test"]
    testClassesDirs = testCompilation.output.classesDirs
    classpath = testCompilation.runtimeDependencyFiles!!

I would never have thought that the content of runtimeDependencyFiles would be the stuff, i would need to put into the classpath, but that acutally did the trick.
This also now enables me to move the task registration from inside the compilation to the root level of the gradle file, which makes it a bit more readable.
If you have any additional comments, please leave them here for me to improve my gradle skills.
